# Legends cut off

Tags: amcharts

Some part of legend is missing. How it possible to show full. Some time my label is long. I searched a lot but I am not found any thing

[image]

```
var chart = am4core.create("product_sale_chart", am4charts.PieChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
    "product": "Brufen 200 mg",
    "size": "94000"
}, {
    "product": "Panadol Ford-20-Tablet-Pack",
    "size": "387000"
}, {
    "product": "Betnovit",
    "size": "4340"
}]

chart.innerRadius = 100;
var label = chart.seriesContainer.createChild(am4core.Label);
label.text = "2019";
label.horizontalCenter = "middle";
label.verticalCenter = "middle";
label.fontSize = 50;
label.labelRadius = -500;
//label.paddingLeft = '50px !important';


var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "size";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "product";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the labels are stretching outside the bounds of the chart.  If this is Amcharts v3 you can reduce the [labelRadius](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#labelRadius) to bring them closer to the center.

**EDIT**

Now that I see your code it's clear you're using Amcharts v4, so instead of `labelRadius` you need to use the following:

```
pieSeries.labels.template.radius = am4core.percent(-40);
```

Here's a [working pen](https://codepen.io/dannybuonocore/pen/NWKOXrW?editors=1010)

[More on labels](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/labels-inside-pie-chart-slices/)

Comment: thanks you. I have updated my question please check it now. I have checked with labelRadius which is not working still.